# Firebase Crashlytics | Are catched exceptions showed or not?

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics

I am using asynctasks and catching exceptions like that below.

I see many errors in my Firebase Crashlytics because of many exceptions. Does this mean that the app crashed or was it because of my code?
Because if I catch them normally no crash appears only the Toast
Can I hide these Exceptions in Firebase somehow?

```
} catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Handler handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All uncaught exceptions will be sent to Crashlytics.  Caught exceptions will not be sent, unless you write specific code to [log them as non-fatal errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#log-excepts).